# Type functions based on property in object

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

I'm trying to type an interface/object correctly so that I can make functions for each object with a certain type. I don't know how to try and explain it better so I will give you some code.

This is my interface:

```js
export interface Activity {
  id: string;
  metaData:
    | {
        type: "createTask";
        data: { taskId: string; taskName: string; user: string };
        task: string;
        taskName: string;
      }
    | {
        type: "deleteTask";
        data: { taskName: string; user: string };
        task: string;
        taskName: string;
      }
    | {
        type: "updateTask";
        data: { taskId: string; taskName: string; user: string };
        task: string;
        taskName: string;
      }
    | {
        type: "createScenario";
        data: {
          scenarioId: string;
          scenarioName: string;
          taskName: string;
          user: string;
        };
        task: string;
        taskName: string;
      }
    | {
        type: "updateScenario";
        data: { scenarioId: string; scenarioName: string; user: string };
        task: string;
        scenario: string;
        taskName: string;
      }
    | {
        type: "deleteScenario";
        data: { scenarioName: string; user: string };
        task: string;
        taskName: string;
      };
}
```

And now from this interface I want to type a function for each different type of activity so that I can lookup that function based on the type.

This is what I tried:

```
export const activityFormatFunctions: Record<
  Activity["metaData"]["type"],
  (activity: Activity) => string
> = {
  createScenario: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  createTask: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  deleteScenario: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  deleteTask: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  updateScenario: (activity) => {
    activity.metaData.data.scenarioName;
    return ""
  },
  updateTask: (activity) => {
    activity.metaData.data.taskName;
    return ""
  },
};
```

The problem is that the "activity" parameter is not narrowed to the activity with the matching type making it so I can only access common properties between all of the different activity types.

In my example above I want to be able to access `scenarioName` in the `updateScenario` scenario function because the Activity interface says it has a `scenarioName`

```
{
  type: "updateScenario";
  data: { scenarioId: string; scenarioName: string; user: string };
  task: string;
  scenario: string;
  taskName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgQWxgQDcEYBPAHgBU5RUkATAZzhsxYGsWBVJBBCQA+OAG8AUHERMAXHBYwoyAOYBuKXAC2wGJgAimPfJoSAvhImUweDtz4ChcALxSAPnADCUYEeB2udzh9YAAbXX9OQLgPXjAmPwCg719UAGVcJExlCCC4hPTM7MEgkPDC4Cycy2tbKJoKGxcggCJsH0SoltamMIiA7pi4FoBXeM7uQY82joqqwSnhsYLgDMriiEWW3vLVopzuy2RUDBw8ACFOSO5xTWlak3rG4A0LCWO0LFwvWeuuehAjFYcEuLD+t2k92e8hmqT+LQ0kLgBUw8jEcD03AAknIFEpVGoMVEAHKYHTyRTKJDqOAjMFQCn46lwMyIyGYriMqnqO5E7ik8l47mvI4oT5nYJ9VABAFAtig8GSJEPYY7fpdNnSFFovlcAXALkE2n0w3M1m8jmmnnKklkg1CgnmUUnL54fITf4MSrAhUypXs6FLcbSjW87XiXU4q2Ejn66PGtBWlma3XRi22wWUx1vD6nb4pPxreYQWXe+VXP0WwOwwv7BYp8P+pHSFh1iBRh3UlNI1vrHJxzvW5v3DP2rNd3lIumJwcp8027hphd6u1pnNivNu4N7PuCUvMctgyvK6vLWu7zYNoyoiO94sd8c0u8bAePwnThmD5Ppxez3nPnIl3ZUc12dcVvjKCIiw2fcfQrKIIQDGwYTVOYNgRMNrx1ADBFfJkaQ-JN52A383x-FdM3w14NFqOAADFkCYc4KAaGwqH4QQkAAGnYZ5RGcOAOKcL0DwjFVWLwMw4AAfkExwkDgeQkGAEg0A0KxnjgABZXRMBRLTMDAFxEOkABtABpRAFMIYgyEoWgogcTjhFMlodD0Qw9BaABdVzah87z5AAChwWzyAoeQbNIcKqAY5hmIkhz7CE7i4HM4RhAAShcURHydCRQEgWA4GwIRFDgULosoOjoC0Iw6JGJAiE4lh5B0vR9MM4z-XaOFoMAuAQuauyKGy5xRCbOAfBgEYoAUlpBhZLjNF6j1gsqkaxom3lptm+bFrMZatSlHdi3W4bwq2kypt0PbhgOo7kROgJzrCygrsm3a5vuzRDs0M80IGoa3tGnLro28KADp3IMa9IZRSGcIgfUUy+-bfsegG-leqrQfG8GLsoaHdM8zB4bh2M7VR27voW37zCAA)

I prefered to declare each Activity in separate interfaces for readability, and declare a union type, to have a fixed length of possibilities.

The big part of the solution lies on the type of your object containing your functions, and find the corresponding union type.

```ts
type FindByType<Union, Type> = Union extends { type: Type } ? Union : never;

type MetadataMap = {
    [K in Activity<TasksUnion>["metaData"]["type"]]: (activity: Activity<FindByType<TasksUnion, K>>) => string
}

export interface Activity<T extends TasksUnion> {
  id: string;
  metaData: T
}

type TasksUnion =
 | CreateTask
 | DeleteTask
 | UpdateTask
 | CreateScenario
 | UpdateScenario
 | DeleteScenario

type TaskType =
 | "createTask"
 | "deleteTask"
 | "updateTask"
 | "createScenario"
 | "updateScenario"
 | "deleteScenario"


interface BaseTask {
    type: TaskType;
}

interface CreateTask extends BaseTask {
    type: "createTask";
    data: { taskId: string; taskName: string; user: string };
    task: string;
    taskName: string;
}

interface DeleteTask extends BaseTask {
    type: "deleteTask";
    data: { taskName: string; user: string };
    task: string;
    taskName: string;
}

interface UpdateTask extends BaseTask {
    type: "updateTask";
    data: { taskId: string; taskName: string; user: string };
    task: string;
    taskName: string;
}

interface CreateScenario extends BaseTask {
    type: "createScenario";
    data: {
        scenarioId: string;
        scenarioName: string;
        taskName: string;
        user: string;
    };
    task: string;
    taskName: string;
}


interface UpdateScenario extends BaseTask {
    type: "updateScenario";
    data: { scenarioId: string; scenarioName: string; user: string };
    task: string;
    scenario: string;
    taskName: string;
}

interface DeleteScenario extends BaseTask {
    type: "deleteScenario";
    data: { scenarioName: string; user: string };
    task: string;
    taskName: string;
};

// Everything correctly typed 
export const activityFormatFunctions: MetadataMap = {
  createScenario: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  createTask: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  deleteScenario: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  deleteTask: (activity) => {
    return ""
  },
  updateScenario: (activity) => {
    activity.metaData.data.scenarioName;
    return ""
  },
  updateTask: (activity) => {
    activity.metaData.data.taskName;
    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I almost got it to work, however I can't seem to get the right typings for when passing an activity into the function. I know I can cast is to any but that feels wrong. Is what I want to do even possible in TypeScript?

Here is an example of what I want to do. I renamed some interfaces also to make it clearer: https://shorturl.at/lvBMT

Comment: I tried but haven't succeded to achieve what you need. I saw this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) that could solve your problem, but haven't managed to apply it in a less verbose way. Keep us up to date if you found the solution

Comment: @hornta your URL redirects somewhere else, could you update it or suggest an edit to my answer to add a playground link ? I am having your same usecase and wish to work a little bit more on it